# Azure custom activities in an Azure Data Factory pipeline run timed out

Tags: azure

I have been trying to follow the steps in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-use-custom-activities
to create a custom activity, but it throw run timed out error in output dataset:

[image]

Pipeline:

```
{
"name": "ADFTutorialPipelineCustom",
"properties": {
    "description": "Use custom activity",
    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "DotNetActivity",
            "typeProperties": {
                "assemblyName": "MyDotNetActivity.dll",
                "entryPoint": "MyDotNetActivityNS.MyDotNetActivity",
                "packageLinkedService": "Destination-BlobStorage",
                "packageFile": "blobcontainer/MyDotNetActivity.zip",
                "extendedProperties": {
                    "SliceStart": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyyMMddHH-mm}', Time.AddMinutes(SliceStart, 0))"
                }
            },
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "OutputDataset"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "00:30:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "retry": 3
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 30
            },
            "name": "MyDotNetActivity",
            "linkedServiceName": "AzureBatchAccount"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2018-01-09T06:00:00Z",
    "end": "2018-01-11T07:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "test2017dec11_hub",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

Output Dataset:

```
{
"name": "OutputDataset",
"properties": {
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "Destination-BlobStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "{slice}.txt",
        "folderPath": "blobcontainer",
        "partitionedBy": [
            {
                "name": "slice",
                "value": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "date": "SliceStart",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd-HH"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 30
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```
    public class MyDotNetActivity : IDotNetActivity
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Execute(IEnumerable<LinkedService> linkedServices, IEnumerable<Dataset> datasets, Activity activity, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        logger.Write("Activity start");

        AzureStorageLinkedService outputLinkedService;

        Dataset outputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset => dataset.Name == activity.Outputs.Single().Name);

        outputLinkedService = linkedServices.First(
            linkedService =>
            linkedService.Name ==
            outputDataset.Properties.LinkedServiceName).Properties.TypeProperties
            as AzureStorageLinkedService;

        string connectionString = outputLinkedService.ConnectionString;

        string folderPath = GetFolderPath(outputDataset);

        UploadFileToBlob(connectionString, folderPath, GetFileName(outputDataset), logger);

        return new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    private static string GetFolderPath(Dataset dataArtifact)
    {
        if (dataArtifact == null || dataArtifact.Properties == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        AzureBlobDataset blobDataset = dataArtifact.Properties.TypeProperties as AzureBlobDataset;
        if (blobDataset == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return blobDataset.FolderPath;
    }

    public void UploadFileToBlob(string blobConnectionString, string blobFolderPath, string fileName, IActivityLogger logger)
    {
        logger.Write("connecting to the blob..");
        var outputStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);
        string output = string.Empty;
        output += "test blob storage";

        var outputBlobUri = new Uri(outputStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint, blobFolderPath + "/" + fileName);
        var outputBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(outputBlobUri, outputStorageAccount.Credentials);
        logger.Write("uploading to the blob URI: {0}", outputBlobUri.ToString());
        outputBlob.UploadText(output);
        logger.Write("upload succeeded");
    }
}
```

Please advise how to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: Hey Lau, did you resolve this issue? Faced the same behavior, but my code was working until 9/9/2018, but after that date have time out errors for custom activities :(

Answer (score 0):

From what you've showing, your activity policy timeout is set to 30 minutes. To change this, edit existing activity policy timeout in your pipeline and set it to a bigger value. i.e.

```
        "policy": {
            "timeout": "02:00:00"
        }
```

To do this, go to your Data Factory and click Author and Deploy action: http://prntscr.com/hxjr9n then click Pipelines http://prntscr.com/hxjrie and edit JSON of your relevant one as I wrote.

Comment: I try to set timeout to 01:00:00 and it still timed out. I think it is not cause by the policy setting. any idea what is the root cause that occur the timed out issue?

Comment: It would be great help if you would provide more data about activities and datasets and pipeline.